# Elasticsearch search delays pulling latest data after indexing

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using the **Official PHP** driver to connect to **Elasticsearch(v 2.3)**, every when I index a new document it takes from **5sec** to **60sec** to be able to get it into my filter results. How can I cut down the delay time to zero?

**Here is my index query**

```
        # Document Body
        $data                    = [];
        $data['time']           = $time;
        $data['unique']         = 1;
        $data['lastACtivity']   = $time;
        $data['bucket']      = 20,
        $data['permission']     = $this->_user->permission; # Extracts User Permission
        $data['ipaddress']      = $this->_client->ipaddress(); # Extracts User IP Address

        # Construct Index
        $indexRequest = [
            'index'     => 'gorocket',
            'type'      => 'log',
            'refresh'   => true,
            'body'      => $data  
        ];

        # Indexing Document
        $confirmation = $client->index( $indexRequest );
```

**And here is my search filter query**

```
# Query array
        $query =[ 'query' => [
                        'filtered' => [
                            'filter' => [
                                'bool' => [
                                            'must' =>[
                                                [
                                                    'match' => [ 'unique' => 1 ]
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                    'range' => [
                                                            'lastACtivity' => [
                                                                'gte'   => $from,
                                                                'lte'   => $to
                                                            ],
                                                            '_cache' => false
                                                    ]
                                                ]
                                            ],
                                            'must_not' => [
                                                [ 'match' => [ 'type' => 'share' ] ],
                                            ]
                                        ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ];

        # Prepare filter parameters
        $filterParams = [
            'index'     => 'gorocket',
            'type'      => 'log',
            'size'      => 20,
            'query_cache' => false,
            'body'      => $query
        ];
        $client->search($filterParams);
```

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 1):

When you index a new document you can specify the `refresh` parameter in order to make the new document available immediately for your next search operation.

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my-index',
    'type' => 'my-type',
    'id' => 123,
    'refresh' => true               <--- add this
];
$response = $client->index($params);
```

The `refresh` parameter is also available on the `bulk` operation if you're using it.

Be aware, though, that refreshing too often can have [negative impacts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-index_.html#index-refresh) on performance.

Comment: Despite adding 'refresh' => true the delay is still there @Val

Comment: Can you show some code to illustrate what you're doing?

Comment: I've edited the question to include code samples. @Val

Comment: There's no `loggedOn` field in the document you index, so that document cannot be retrieved by the search since it's a must constraint.

Comment: It's variable that gets passed (Unix timestamp). The above code works, only that it delays retrieving the document. @Val

Comment: What I'm saying is that when you index the document, there's no `loggedOn` field in it and in your query you're adding a constraint on that field, which doesn't exist in the document, so it cannot be retrieved. Only when that field is added (I guess a few seconds later in some other process)

Comment: Ooh!.. It was a mistake that happened when i was pasting the code. I've corrected the code samples. @Val

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121361/discussion-between-julius-tm-and-val).

Comment: Ok, do you get 20 docs in your search response? maybe the one you've indexed is at the 21st position. Have you tried to increase the size to see if it's there?

Comment: The records gets returned, only that there is a delay. I want the document to be instantly available through the php driver after indexing it.

Comment: How do you test that delay? Since you're only retrieving 20 docs, how do you know that the new document is not the 100th document in the results, but doesn't show up because you only take the first 20?

Comment: I have only 5 documents so far. when I index a new document the search filter is supposed to return 6 documents, instead it returns 5. But after some seconds( While repeating the search query again and again ) the 6th document gets returned. So it's not a results size problem @Val

Comment: That small piece of information would have been helpful early on ;-)

Comment: Apologies for communicating it late. So, what's the solution? @Val

Comment: Can you try to call `$client->indices()->refresh()` after indexing your document?

Comment: It still behaves the same way. When i search using CURL the new added document becomes available instantly after being indexed. @Val

Answer (score 0):

There is a refresh option provided, which needs a value (in seconds) to refresh the index. For example, if you update something in index, it gets written in the index but not ready for reading until the index is refreshed.

Refresh can be set to true for refreshing the index as soon as any change happens. This needs to be very carefully thought, because many times, it downgrades your performance as its an overkill to refresh for each small operation, plus many bulk refreshes can make the index busy.

Tip: Use an elasticsearch plugin, such as kopf and see more such options like refresh rate, to configure.